# Centralising data in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have matrices with rows that need to be centralised. In other words each row has trailing zeros at both ends, while the actual data is between the trailing zeros. However, I need the number of trailing zeros to be equal at both ends or in other words what I call the data (values between the trailing zeros) to be centred at the middle of the row. Here is an example:

```
array:
[[0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]]

centred_array:
[[0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I hope that explains it well enough so that you can see some of the issues I am having. One, I am not guaranteed a even value for the size of the "data" so the function needs to pick a centre for even values which is consistent; also this is the case for rows (rows might have an even size which means one placed needs to be chosen as the centre).

EDIT: I should probably note that I have a function that does this; its just that I can get 10^3 number of rows to centralise and my function is too slow, so efficiency would really help.

@HYRY

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]])
cd = []
(x, y) = np.shape(a)
for row in a:
    trim = np.trim_zeros(row)
    to_add = y - np.size(trim)
    a = to_add / 2
    b = to_add - a
    cd.append(np.pad(trim, (a, b), 'constant', constant_values=(0, 0)).tolist())
result = np.array(cd)
print result

[[0 0 1 2 0 2 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: post your code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def centralise(arr):
    # Find the x and y indexes of the nonzero elements:
    x, y = arr.nonzero()

    # Find the index of the left-most and right-most elements for each row:
    nonzeros = np.bincount(x)
    nonzeros_idx = nonzeros.cumsum()
    left = y[np.r_[0, nonzeros_idx[:-1]]]
    right = y[nonzeros_idx-1]

    # Calculate how much each y has to be shifted
    shift = ((arr.shape[1] - (right-left) - 0.5)//2 - left).astype(int)
    shift = np.repeat(shift, nonzeros) 
    new_y = y + shift

    # Create centered_arr
    centered_arr = np.zeros_like(arr)
    centered_arr[x, new_y] = arr[x, y]
    return centered_arr

arr = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]])
print(centralise(arr))
```

yields

```
[[0 0 1 2 0 2 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0]]
```

---

A benchmark comparing the original code to centralise:

```
def orig(a):
    cd = []
    (x, y) = np.shape(a)
    for row in a:
        trim = np.trim_zeros(row)
        to_add = y - np.size(trim)
        a = to_add / 2
        b = to_add - a
        cd.append(np.pad(trim, (a, b), 'constant', constant_values=(0, 0)).tolist())
    result = np.array(cd)
    return result
```

---

```
In [481]: arr = np.tile(arr, (1000, 1))

In [482]: %timeit orig(arr)
10 loops, best of 3: 140 ms per loop

In [483]: %timeit centralise(arr)
1000 loops, best of 3: 537 µs per loop

In [486]: (orig(arr) == centralise(arr)).all()
Out[486]: True
```

Comment: Wow this is a lot faster! And 250k? You are something else sir.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have 10^3 rows in your array, you can probably afford a python loop if you'd like a more explicit solution:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]])

for i, r in enumerate(a):
    w = np.where(r!=0)[0]
    nend = len(r) - w[-1] - 1
    nstart = w[0]
    shift = (nend - nstart)//2
    a[i] = np.roll(r, shift)

print(a)
```

gives:

```
[[0 0 1 2 0 2 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `np.apply_along_axis`:

```
import numpy as np

def centerRow(a):
  i = np.nonzero(a <> 0)
  ifirst = i[0][0]
  ilast = i[0][-1]
  count = ilast-ifirst+1
  padleft = (np.size(a) - count) / 2
  padright = np.size(a) - padleft - count
  b = np.r_ [ np.repeat(0,padleft), a[ifirst:ilast+1], np.repeat(0,padright) ]
  return b

arr = np.array(
[[0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]]
  )

barr = np.apply_along_axis(centerRow, 1, arr)
print barr
```

Comment: I had a look at np.apply_along_axis when attempting this. It is interesting except I don't know whether it is faster than just iterating over the arrays normally; since I took a look at the source code and it seems like it was designed with efficiency for higher dimensional arrays than 2D. Do you know if this is valid?

Comment: Sorry, don't know - the best is to just benchmark it.

Answer (score 1):

**Algorithm**:

1. find positions of non-zero values on the row of length `n`
2. find the difference, `d`, between 1st and the last non-zero element
3. store meaningful vector, `x`, in the row given by length `d`
4. find the mid-point of `d`, `d_m`, if it is even, get the right element
5. find the mid-point of row length, `n_m`, if it is even, pick the right
6. subtract `d_m-d` from `n_m` and place `x` at this position in the row of zeros of length `n`
7. repeat for all rows

---

**Quick Octave Prototype (Will Soon post Python version):**

```
mat = [[0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]];

newMat = zeros(size(mat)); %new matrix to be filled
n = size(mat, 2);

for i = 1:size(mat,1)
    newRow = newMat(i,:);
    nonZeros = find(mat(i,:));

    x = mat(i, nonZeros(1):nonZeros(end));
    d = nonZeros(end)- nonZeros(1);
    d_m = ceil(d/2);
    n_m = ceil(n/2);

    newRow(n_m-d_m:n_m-d_m+d) = x;
    newMat(i,:) = newRow;
end

newMat
> [[0 0 1 2 0 2 1 0 0]
   [0 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0]
   [0 0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0]]
```